# TypeScript - Cast SubClass to SuperClass

Tags: typescript

is there a simple solution to the following problem?
I want to cast the object B into the object A.

Thank your for your solutions.

```
export interface A {
  a: string;
}

export interface B extends A {
  b: string;
}

const b: B = {
  a: 'test1',
  b: 'test2'
};

console.log(b); //output: {a:'test1', b:'test2'}

console.log(b as A);  //output: {a:'test1', b:'test2'}, but i want {a:'test1'}
```

Comment: There is no *casting* in TS. The entire type system only exists at compile time. Using `as` is a *type assertion* and tells the compiler "treat this *as if* it's another type for the purposes of type checking". There is no actual change of the shape of the data and it's a very common source of bugs where a programmer asserted something is the wrong type.

Comment: If you can use `classes` instead of `interfaces`, than this library may help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer#plaintoclass

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces are just a compile-time construct to ensure typesafety. You could create data like `{'f': 'foo'} as any as A` and it would still be perfectly valid, altough your data does not match the interface at all.

To "cast" this, you'd need to manually create a new object: `const a = {a: b.a}`.